# How to select Name, Second Name and Name_Chairrr from 3 tables of MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relationship

Here is scheme of DB. How to select Name, Second Name and Name_Chairrr from 3 tables of MySQL????

[image]

```
SELECT p.Name, p.Second_Name, c.Name_CHAIRRR 
FROM Professors p  
JOIN pchairs pc ON pc.ID_Professor = p.ID_professor 
JOIN Chairs c ON c.ID_chair = pc.ID_Chair
```

Comment: You what you tried to do?   . try JOIN

Comment: I have tried use LEFT JOIN, but having errors

Comment: update your question with your querycode  so we can try to improve it ..

Comment: SELECT p.Name, p.Second_Name, c.Name_CHAIRRR
FROM Professors p
JOIN pchairs pc ON pc.ID_Professor = p.ID_professor
JOIN Chairs c ON c.ID_chair = pc.ID_Chair

Comment: The code seems right .. there are errors .? in this case show me the error message please?

Comment: There was problem with alias.. Already fixed, thanks.....

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the tables together and use aliases. Try this

```
SELECT p.Name, p.Second_Name, c.Name_CHAIRRR
FROM Professors p
JOIN pchairs pc ON pc.ID_Professor = p.ID_professor
JOIN Chairs c ON c.ID_chair = pc.ID_Chair
```

Answer (score 0):

I think youre looking for this

```
select
    p.name,
    p.second_name,
    c.name_chairrr
from
    professors p
inner join
    pchairs pc
on
    p.id_professor=pc.id_professor
inner join
    chairs c
on
    pc.id_chair=c.id_chair
```